# Rails Detect If User's Very First Visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm trying to make the user fill out a questionnaire if it is their first time visiting the site.

My controllers are set up like this:

```
class MainController < BaseController
end

class BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :first_time_visiting?
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def first_time_visiting?
    if session[:first_time].nil?
      session[:first_time] = 1
      redirect_to questionnaire_path unless current_user
    end
  end
end
```

When I close the browser and re-open it though, I always get redirected to the questionnaire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set a cookie in the browser for that user in order to allow detection at a later time, i.e. after the user closes the browser.  Setting and reading cookies in rails is easy.  Checkout the documentation for some example usage. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

Comment: For some reason I thought session stuff already got put in a cookie. Easy enough though: `cookies.permanent[:first_time] = 1`

Comment: session stuff does go into a cookie, but not a persistent one.  That cookie gets cleared when the browser closes. You want to set the "expires" on your cookie for future date, leaving it nil will cause it to be deleted on browser close also.

Comment: Which is why this is not really possible.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled on this question, my solution is just jQUery and involves setting localStorage (make sure you have a polyfill). Hide the element you want to only show once.

```
$(function() {
  if ( localStorage.getItem('visited') ) {
    return;
  }

  var $el = $('.only-show-on-first-visit');
  $el.slideDown(800);
  localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
  $el.find('.close').click(function() {
    $el.slideUp();
  });
});


// polyfill
if (!('localStorage' in window)) {
  window.localStorage = {
    _data       : {},
    setItem     : function(id, val) { return this._data[id] = String(val); },
    getItem     : function(id) { return this._data.hasOwnProperty(id) ? this._data[id] : undefined; },
    removeItem  : function(id) { return delete this._data[id]; },
    clear       : function() { return this._data = {}; }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'last logged in time' field on your user table. When that is nil do foo and !nil do bar.

Comment: The questionnaire does not necessarily require a user to be logged in.