# Rails 3: How to tell if a user has visited a page before?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

I have a Rails app (using Authlogic for authentication) with a simple jquery animation that I only want to run once upon first page load. I know that the key is to check cookies or something to see if the user has visited the page before. Please forgive my n00bness, I know little to nothing about HTTP cookies or sessions.

So, what's the best way to see if a visiting user (even if they haven't logged in) is viewing a page for the first time?

**EDIT:** Ok, so I realize I wasn't being entirely clear.

I've spent hours looking at similar questions and reading the Rails API Docs for cookies and sessions and I still can't visualize how to implement a **visited?** function for each page in my site that will only be set to "true" after the user has visited the page the first time. I looked at the supposed "duplicate" question **[Rails Detect If User's Very First Visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988300/rails-detect-if-users-very-first-visit)** and the respective answers and still can't figure it out.

Here's my "Pages" controller:

```
def home
    @title = "Home"
end

def contact
    @title = "Contact Us"
end
```

dd

And my jquery javascript that does a simple animation:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
if (!$.cookie('visited')) {
    $('.title .flying-text').css({opacity:0});
    $('.title .active-text').animate({
        opacity:1,
        marginTop: "-150px",
        }, 5000);
}
 });
```

I only want it to show if the user HAS NOT visited the page before. I have no idea how to properly set a cookie in Rails, nor where to put it, nor how to make sure that the animation script can access that exact same cookie value. Can someone give me a hand?

~Dan

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988300/rails-detect-if-users-very-first-visit

Comment: Edited to make my question clearer. I looked at the other question and still cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a cookie like this:

```
cookies[:welcomed] = {:value => true, :expires => Time.now + 6.months}
```

and from jquery make a wee function

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=", ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i += 1) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') { 
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and call it #in js

```
  if (readCookie('welcomed') == null){}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ignore the cookie from Javascript.

Using the question referenced as a duplicate, use a permanent cooke and on the first run, set a class on your body from Rails (let's say `first-run`). Then, have your javascript check and see if `body` has class `first-run`. At that point, you can have javascript execute it's first run code.